# From JS to Java?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I know GWT beeing able to code in Java and translate the cope on compilation to JS.

What about the other way around? Is there something that can translate JS to Java code?

Comment: @jAndy that just patently false

Comment: But Rhino and Nashorn would both be serverside not client side be aware of that! On the other hand you could also see some samples for Rhino on Mozilla Developers site. But dont expect anything fancy like writing JavaScript on HTML page and converting it to Java. Tats never possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino).

From their site:

> Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide scripting to end users. It is embedded in J2SE 6 as the default Java scripting engine.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Rhino (by Mozilla) there is also [Nashorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29) (by Oracle) (which btw. means "Rhino" in German), which is an official JS implementation in Java.

It will be available OpenSource with Java8 in 2013.